# How to parameterise the cucumber options tags from jenkins in karate

Tags: karate

I have below java class which runs with cucumberOptions

@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@userManagement"})
public class IC_API_Tests_Runner {
  runner code here
}

```
From jenkins I am passing below command ti run the tests

clean test "-Dkarate.env=$WhereToRun" "-Dbvt.tags=@userManagement"

I am able to fetch the value of 'bvt.tags' using below command
bvtTags = karate.properties['bvt.tags'];

Now I need to pass the 'bvtTags' value to the CucumberOptions.

I tried

    @CucumberOptions(tags = {"bvtTags"})
public class IC_API_Tests_Runner {
  runner code here
}
But 'bvtTags' value is not substituted in the CucumberOptions. But I am able to print the value of 'bvtTags' with print statement in karate code.

Any help will be great help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do dynamic changing of the `@CucumberOptions` like that.

Use the API for dynamically choosing tests, see this example: [`DemoTestSelected.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestSelected.java).

Then do something like this (please change for your environment):

```
String tags = System.getProperty("bvt.tags");
List<String> tags = Arrays.asList(tags);
```

EDIT: actually you don't need to do any of this. (I guess that you will never read the docs :)

Please refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#command-line

```
-Dkarate.options="--tags @userManagement"
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine :) Thank you for quick and accurate reply :)